# partial derivative of a function of two R.V.s respect to the expected value of one R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, partial-derivative, expected-value

Consider two **independent** random variables $X$ and $Y$, and $X \geq 0$, $Y \geq 0$. Let $Z = f(X, Y)$

Is it possible to calculate the partial derivative of $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ respect to $\mathbb{E}(X)$, i.e. $\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbb{E}(X)} \mathbb{E}(Z)$?

More specifically, I would like to find what property $f(\cdot)$ should have to enforce the partial derivative is greater than 0,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbb{E}(X)} \mathbb{E}(Z) \geq 0
\end{equation}

For example, polynomials with all positive coefficient should have it hold.

(Should I say $\{X\}$ is a (infinite) set of arbitrary R.V.s? Because the goal I'd like to achieve is to find some property of $f(\cdot)$ that $\mathbb{E}(f(X_1, Y)) \geq \mathbb{E}(f(X_2, Y))$ for any $X_1, X_2$ that $\mathbb{E}(X_1) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_2)$ )

I'd really appreciate for any hint.

Comment: In what sense does the expected value of $X$ change?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, I am sorry that I didn't make it clear. I just edited the question. Hope the edits make sense.